# IIS7.5 HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I know this had been asked several times on this forum and I followed almost all of the solutions posted. But none of it gave me solved my problem.

I am trying to deploy a webapi that I built to an IIS server version 7.5
Running the application works on my local machine but not on the server.

I am having this message when browsing the webapi:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

These the dotnet isntalled on my server:
[dotnetinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r47CB.png)

This my project configuration:
[projectconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmZ4a.png)

And this is how I publish:
[publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4xD.png)

I have tried:
publishing both framework-dependent and portable - produces HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure
publishing both framework-dependent and x64 (Our server is a 64bit) - produces a Error 404 - Not found when browsing
publishing self-contained and x64 - produces a Error 404 - Not found when browsing

I hope someone can point out what I am missing here to make my webapi work.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You need to show the complete 502.5 error page, as it contains other important information.

Comment: Here is the content of the error page: HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Start up Failure
Common soutions to this issue:
-The application process failed to start
-The application process started but then stopped
-The application started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
-Check the system event log for error messages
-Enable looging the application process' stdout messages
-Attach debugger to the application and inspect

Comment: Please edit your question to include the well formatted page. Never post it as comment.

Comment: Confirm that the app pool's 32-bit setting is correct:
Select the app pool in IIS Manager's Application Pools.
Select Advanced Settings under Edit Application Pool in the Actions panel.
Set Enable 32-Bit Applications: 
If deploying a 32-bit (x86) app, set the value to True.
If deploying a 64-bit (x64) app, set the value to False.try to download  .NET Core Runtime 2.2 [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755562/http-error-502-5-ancm-out-of-process-startup-failure-after-upgrading-to-asp-ne