# How to get event log files from Azure app service without Cloud Explorer?

Tags: logging, event-log, visual-studio-2022, azure-storage-explorer

I have an Azure app service. In Visual Studio 2019 I can do this to get event logs from it:

1. Open **Cloud Exlorer** window (**View -> Cloud Explorer**).
2. Log in with my Azure credentials.
3. Expand subscription, then resource group, then app service.
4. Expand the folder **Log Files**
5. Doubleclick **eventlog.xml** to download it.

In Visual Studio 2022 there is no Cloud Explorer. They recommend us to use Azure Storage Explorer instead. I have not been able to find the event log file in Storage Explorer.

Does anyone know how to get it without Visual Studio 2019 - either from a GUI or from a command line?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer in this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#troubleshoot-on-azure-app-service

> To access the Application Event Log, use the Diagnose and solve problems blade in the Azure portal:
>
> 1. In the Azure portal, open the app in App Services.
> 2. Select Diagnose and solve problems.
> 3. Select the Diagnostic Tools heading.
> 4. Under Support Tools, select the Application Events button.
> 5. Examine the latest error provided by the IIS AspNetCoreModule or IIS AspNetCoreModule V2 entry in the Source column.
>
> An alternative to using the Diagnose and solve problems blade is to examine the Application Event Log file directly using Kudu:
>
> 1. Open Advanced Tools in the Development Tools area. Select the Go→ button. The Kudu console opens in a new browser tab or window.
> 2. Using the navigation bar at the top of the page, open Debug console and select CMD.
> 3. Open the LogFiles folder.
> 4. Select the pencil icon next to the eventlog.xml file.
> 5. Examine the log. Scroll to the bottom of the log to see the most recent events.